# What is the difference between offline and online projects, with respect to .NET?

Tags: .net, windows

What's the difference between online and offline projects, with respect to the .NET environment?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that online projects is downloaded before you can start them. Offline ones, on the other hand, are persisted locally.

Comment: Sounde like pure guessing.

Comment: Your screenshot refers to project _templates_, while your answers seems to refer to compiled projects?!?

Comment: @UweKeim I guess we need more context.